# Shell - Remove space before variable in alias

Tags: bash, alias

Typing `myAlias 10` or even better `myAlias10` should execute `ssh user@127.0.0.10`

`alias myAlias="ssh user@127.0.0.${1}"` produces `ssh user@127.0.0.`

When I echo it, it is displayed as `ssh user@127.0.0. 10` with a space.

How to remove the space ?

Comment: An alias does not take a parameter. Therefore,  `user@127.0.0.${1}` does not make sense. Since there are "only" 256 possible values for `$1`, you can loop over the integers from 0 to 255 and create 256 aliases on the fly. But,it would be much simpler to create a function named `myAlias` instead of an alias, and you could use `$1` safely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use double quotes, the variable is expanded right when parsing the alias definition.

Aliases don't take parameters, they just append the remaining words - you can't "remove the space", it has already been parsed.

Use a function instead, functions take arguments:

```sh
myssh () {
    ssh user@127.0.0."$1"
}
```